# How to open the first accordion panel (on a Shopiy theme) on page load, right now they are all collapsed on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, accordion, liquid

How to open the first accordion panel (on a Shopiy theme) on page load, right now they are all collapsed on load, I am new to coding, and i want to change the code so that when the page loads, the first accordion panel is open, while the others stay closed when page loads. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
theme.collapsibles = (function() {

  var selectors = {
    trigger: '.collapsible-trigger',
    module: '.collapsible-content',
    moduleInner: '.collapsible-content__inner'
  };

  var classes = {
    hide: 'hide',
    open: 'is-open',
    autoHeight: 'collapsible--auto-height'
  };

  var isTransitioning = false;

  function init() {
    $(selectors.trigger).each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      var state = $el.hasClass(classes.open);
      $el.attr('aria-expanded', state);
    });

    // Event listeners (hack for modals)
    $('body, .modal__inner').on('click', selectors.trigger, function() {
      if (isTransitioning) {
        return;
      }

      isTransitioning = true;

      var $el = $(this);
      var isOpen = $el.hasClass(classes.open);
      var moduleId = $el.attr('aria-controls');
      var $module = $('#' + moduleId);
      var height = $module.find(selectors.moduleInner).outerHeight();
      var isAutoHeight = $el.hasClass(classes.autoHeight);

      // If isAutoHeight, set the height to 0 just after setting the actual height
      // so the closing animation works nicely
      if (isOpen && isAutoHeight) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          height = 0;
          setTransitionHeight($module, height, isOpen, isAutoHeight);
        }, 0);
      }

      if (isOpen && !isAutoHeight) {
        height = 0;
      }

      $el
        .attr('aria-expanded', !isOpen)
        .toggleClass(classes.open, !isOpen);

      setTransitionHeight($module, height, isOpen, isAutoHeight);
    });
  }

  function setTransitionHeight($module, height, isOpen, isAutoHeight) {
    $module
      .removeClass(classes.hide)
      .prepareTransition()
      .css('height', height)
      .toggleClass(classes.open, !isOpen);

    if (!isOpen && isAutoHeight) {
      var o = $module;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        o.css('height','auto');
        isTransitioning = false;
      }, 500);
    } else {
      isTransitioning = false;
    }
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
})();
```

Comment: actually its in the code: setTransitionHeight does it. It simple changes the height. it remebers state(isOpen== true when open):
---
$el.attr('aria-expanded', !isOpen)
        .toggleClass(classes.open, !isOpen)
--
So whats your question?

Comment: So what exactly do I need to change in the code to have the accordion tab start open - on page load - (expanded), to begin with, and then the users has the option to close them when they click.

Comment: setTransitionHeight($module, height, isOpen, isAutoHeight); <- set the parameters accordingly.